# Ant move and pattern for files' name

Tags: regex, ant, rename, move

i need to move a file from dir A to dir B with ant.

File's name can have unspecified extension such as logo.png, logo.gif, logo.jpg and go on.

Can you help me, please?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

This snippet moves all files with name starting with `logo.` from `A` to `B`.  Perhaps you are looking for something similar?

```
  <move todir="B">
    <fileset dir="A">
      <include name="**/logo.*"/>
    </fileset>
  </move>
```

Comment: Sorry, i, also, need to copy rename it

Comment: @Premier You should give some example of what you want to do by editing your question so that someone can respond

Comment: thank you. I have mistaken to make the question. In my app i can have an image with name "logo" and unknow suffix. The suffix can be ".png",".jpg",".bmp",... I need to copy the image in a directory B and rename the image to "logo.png". So, i've solved with a custom task, but i'm interested to your solution.

Comment: @Premier Perhaps this stackoverflow discussion is of some help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244049/renaming-files-during-ant-copy